# Passing parameter in EL action doesn't work with RequestScoped bean

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, el

**Edit:** using JSF scopes now and JSF managedbean instead of CDI as it doesn't work with CDI beans regardless of RequestScoped, ConversationScoped or SessionScoped.

I'm trying to pass a parameter to a function on a bean like this:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.update(wp.nr)}" value="Update" />
```

However the update function is only called if I make the bean ViewScoped, not when it is RequestScoped. Using ViewScoped doesn't seem to work for now but I would like to know whether the use of at least ViewScoped is a requirement for passing parameters in EL calls in the action or that RequestScoped should work and there is something else going on.

This is on glassfish 3.1.2.2

The bean looks like this

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@RequestScoped
public class FiliaalBean implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FiliaalBean.class.getName());

    @Inject
    TestEJB testEjb;

    // Removed some data member and  getter and setters

    public String update(int wpnr) {
        LOG.info("TEST " + Integer.toString(wpnr));
        // TODO call testEjb
        return "view?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true";
    }
}
```

Comment: `update` will probably need to be a `void` (not sure though)?

Comment: This confuses me. CDI does not have a `ViewScoped` (You *are* using a CDI managed bean). Where are your `@RequestScoped` and `@ViewScoped` imported from?

Comment: @kolossus I was getting confused to so I accidently used ViewScoped instead of ConversationScoped and as my IDE added to import I didn't notice the incorrect package. Using CDI style just doesn't seem to work in this case regardless of which scope. Completely switching to JSF style helped with other issues ViewScoped was causing but it still won't work with RequestScoped. Updated my question.